# ASP Identity : Binding Sessions To Request Url (Sub Domains)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I don't think the title of the question is particularly accurate but that's how best i could title it.

Without summarizing, I have an MVC app hosted on Microsoft Azure. The app was built for multiple institutions (each connecting to a separate database) but the Login Module (Asp Identity) is in a central database (users are identified by their institution code). So during deployment, a sub domain is created (still pointing to the app on azure).

My problem is, the app has no regard for the Request Url, the sessions are maintained across domains. This is a serious problem because i cache User data (by session). So if a user Logs in on "*domain1.myapp.com*" , then opens another tab , logs into "*domain2.myapp.com*" , all data cached for the user logged in for "*domain1*" will be used for the user logged in at "*domain2*". The app doesn't bother to get data for the user in "*domain2*" since the key for that data value is already present in the session cache.

Okay, I hope the problem is understood. How do i get past this.

Ideas ? implementation ?

**EDIT 1**

I insert data into the cache by,

```
HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("KEY", "VALUE", null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

Comment: You use the term "session cache". Does that mean you are using `HttpContext.Session` to store the user data, are you using a cache such as `HttpContext.Cache` or `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache`, or are you using another method to cache the data? Please show your cache configuration code.

Comment: @NightOwl888 I'm Using _HttpRuntime.Cache_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your caching strategy needs to change when you cache per user and per domain. The simplest approach is just to add the domain and user name to the cache key, which will keep each cache in a separate per user and per domain bucket. Make sure you put a delimiter between the values to ensure uniqueness of the key.

```
var domain = HttpContext.Request.Url.DnsSafeHost;
var user = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
var key = "__" + domain + "_" + user + "_" + "KEY";

HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(key, "VALUE", null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

> Note that if you use `HttpContext.Session`, it will automatically put different domain information into separate buckets because it is based on a cookie (which by default is domain specific). However, [`HttpContext.Session` comes with its own set of problems](https://brockallen.com/2012/04/07/think-twice-about-using-session-state/).